# Hide iframe with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

```
$('.post-content').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var count = $this.children().length;
    if (count > 2) {
        var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
            if ($this.children('iframe.twitter-tweet').length) {
                console.log("Exists!");
                sel = $this.children().slice(2);
                console.log(sel);
                sel.hide();
                clearInterval(checkExist);
            }
        }, 100); // check every 100ms
    }
});
```

---

```
Exists!
/blog/ (line 65)
Object[p, p, p, p, p, p, p, iframe#twitter-widget-0.twitter-tweet, blockquote.twitter-tweet, p, p, p, p, p, p]
```

The only element that is not hidden is the iframe. My question is why if the hide() is only applied when the iframe was rendered?

More details:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="pt">
    <p>Test your music knowledge with Quiz This It, our weekly trivia challenge. This week&#39;s subject: The Strokes <a href="http://t.co/XZIjJO6GSp">http://t.co/XZIjJO6GSp</a>
    </p>&mdash; NME (@NME) <a href="https://twitter.com/NME/statuses/425328322412052480">20 janeiro 2014</a>
</blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/75u6s/5/

---

Real problem demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/4FEkb/

**I want to hide all elements.**

Comment: Please provide more information, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @BlackSheep basically i need to hide an embedded tweet.

Comment: @BlackSheep full demo now.

Comment: Your fiddle works for me! Why don't you hide the `.post-content` element? What the parent is hidden it's children inherit the property.

Comment: @BlackSheep i can't hide the whole parent. I am doing a slice to preserve always the first two P elements. It Works for you due the web speed probably. thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="kite"><blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="pt">
    <p>Test your music knowledge with Quiz This It, our weekly trivia challenge. This week&#39;s subject: The Strokes <a href="http://t.co/XZIjJO6GSp">http://t.co/XZIjJO6GSp</a>
    </p>&mdash; NME (@NME) <a href="https://twitter.com/NME/statuses/425328322412052480">20 janeiro 2014</a>
    </blockquote></div>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

$("#kite").html("");
```

Comment: I don't want to create new elements, and if the iframe load is slow this will not work.

Comment: In that case you can use $("#kite").hide();

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job.

```
if ($('iframe.twitter-tweet-rendered').contents().find('body').children().length > 0) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You had an error on this `sel = $this.children().slice(2);` line.
It is to be

```
sel = $(this).children().slice(2);
```

Or you can do

```
$(this).children().slice(2).hide();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It seems you haven't cached an object so far, OP is caching the object, `var $this = $(this);`.